# How to make TButton look 3d?

Tags: forms, user-interface, delphi, button, 3d

I wrote a program that a user can use to draw shapes, place actual buttons and other tools on a Form and make them active. However, I noticed that there is a big difference in how a TButton on this form and TButton of a form in design mode look. Take a look at the following images.

This button is from my program and right below the image is how I create this button on this form:
[image]

```
constructor TMakerButton.Create(r:TRect;form:TForm);
begin
   inherited Create(r,form);
   myType := totButton;
   name := 'Button';
   caption := 'Button';
   lines := TStringList.Create;
   lines.Clear;
   button := TButton.Create(form);
   button.Parent := form;
   button.caption := string(caption);
   button.Tag := LongInt(Self);

   if form is TMakerFrm then
   begin
      button.Enabled := false;
   end;
   button.OnClick := ButtonClick;
   button.OnMouseMove := ButtonMove;

   myControl := button;
   with bounds do
   button.SetBounds(left,top,right-left,bottom-top);
end;
```

Here is a TButton in design mode in delphi Compiler. See how it looks like 3d with its polished glassy look:

[image]

What is interesting is that the base class for my program's button and delphi compiler is **TButton** So, why do they look so different and how to do you make my Button look the same?

Comment: Do you have Runtime Themes enabled in your project options?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just checked and it is enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Button is disabled. These should be the reason for the different look.

Comment: Really! OMG...All these years of working with delphi, I had no idea.... It works...